# Preparing pie chart to add to scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

After being helped in a previous post of mine, [Customizing points in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764895/customizing-points-in-r), I've decided to make a scatterplot of pie charts; the problem I'm having is preparing the individual pie chart for graphing.

I have four variables (let's call them firstvar through fourthvar) that are each either 1 or 0. I want to map each quadrant of the pie chart to a variable and shade that quadrant if the variable is one and leave it white otherwise. The way I'm headed with the code I'd have a series of nested ifelse() calls that I cannot get to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated, my code is below:

```
test <- c(1,1,1,1)
lbls <- c("PY1 NM Sig", "PY2 NM Sig", "PY1 FM Sig", "PY2 FM Sig" )
pie(test, labels = lbls, 
    col=ifelse(data$firstvar>0 , "blue", "white"))
```

Comment: you should probably i) produce a reproducible example, ii) clarify whether you're using ggplot or base graphics

Comment: I would also caution that pie charts are almost never the right graphic for displaying the information you're intent on displaying.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I will make my questions clearer in the future.